Azure function app authenticating using managed identity with scope
Let me preface this by saying that I'm relatively new to Azure, and am very much still getting my sea legs.
We have an Azure Function App that's leveraging a blob trigger. This app needs to turn around and call our APIs. These APIs are set up as an Enterprise Application/App Registration and requires the scope API.Access.
What I'm trying to do is to authenticate against this scope from the Function App, but have been unsuccessful in doing so. When doing something like this
var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId, options);
            _accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(["api://49c35b57-3e95-4f80-a8fa-5536616f337c/API.Access"]), cancellationToken);

we wind up with an error like this:
Content:
{"statusCode":400,"message":"No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId.","correlationId":"c7adf6b5-0388-4c11-94f9-211ee3e31c43"}

The call to the IMDS service actually seems to be timing out from what I can tell.
If we try to SSH to the Function App and verify that IMDS is running (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/TROUBLESHOOTING.md#azure-app-service-and-azure-functions-managed-identity) it appears that it is not.
Is what we're trying to do just not supported? Another way to do it would be to set up an App Registration for the Function App with delegated access to the API.Access scope, and then use client secret credentials to authenticate. But, it seemed more ideal to use a managed identity since that doesn't require us to maintain a separate client secret and such.

Hi! Have not tested this myself, but seems like you can set these permissions in the enterprise applications section via Powershell. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/grant-graph-api-permission-to-managed-identity-object/ba-p/2792127?lightbox-message-images-2792127=313355iBCB51B817AC167D9. However, not visable in the portal apparently.


Content: {"statusCode":400,"message":"No User Assigned or Delegated Managed Identity found for specified ClientId/ResourceId/PrincipalId.","}

You are getting this error because you have enabled system managed identity but using the code for user assigned managed identity to fetch token.
If you want to use the below code then you need to assign an user assigned managed identity in your function app.


You need to add API.Access in the registered app as shown below.



Grant access to this app role in API permission blade. Search with the App registration name in APIs my organization uses.


Click on the app name and you will see the custom app role API.Access is showing to add.

Once added, grant Admin consent.

var options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions();
var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential(clientId, options);

var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "<clientId>/API.Access" });
var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, cancellationToken);

Make sure to grant permission to the scope API.Access in the enterprise application created by enabling the system managed identity in function app. I have used the below PowerShell script for the same.
In order to execute the below script, click on the API.Access in API permission blade to get the details like Resource APP ID which will be needed in the script.

Connect-AzureAD

$TenantID="{tenantId}"
$ResourceAppId = "{ResourceAppId of API.Access}" 
$DisplayNameOfMSI="{functionApp Name}"
$PermissionName = "API.Access"

$MSI = (Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "displayName eq '$DisplayNameOfMSI'")
Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
$GraphServicePrincipal = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal -Filter "appId eq '$ResourceAppId'"
$AppRole = $GraphServicePrincipal.AppRoles | 
Where-Object {$_.Value -eq $PermissionName -and $_.AllowedMemberTypes -contains "Application"}

New-AzureAdServiceAppRoleAssignment -ObjectId $MSI.ObjectId -PrincipalId $MSI.ObjectId -ResourceId $GraphServicePrincipal.ObjectId -Id $AppRole.Id

Once the script is successfully executed then you can verify that the custom role has granted access in the enterprise application created by enabling system managed identity in function app.

To fetch the token for system managed identity, use the below code. Here you can use scope either <client or application Id>/API.Access or api://<client or application Id>/.default
var credential = new ManagedIdentityCredential();
var tokenRequestContext = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "<client or application Id>/API.Access" });
var accessToken = await credential.GetTokenAsync(tokenRequestContext, cancellationToken);



Thank you! I think we're closer now. When configuring it to use the user managed identity as suggested, we're getting a 500 when attempting to retrieve the token. Looking in the sign-in logs in Entra, we're seeing this: AppId: '{appId}' can not use Managed Service Identity (MSI) as audience in token as it is unsupported. MSI should not be set as audience as it does not accept tokens.. In googling that error, I'm not seeing anything super obvious.

Also, this is probably a dumb question, but when fetching the token using a system managed identity, why could I not use the scope api://<client or application Id>/API.Access ? The API application is currently expecting the audience to be api://<application id>, so if I just set the scope to <client or application id>/API.Access it will fail audience validation.

Can you try with api://application I'd/. default

When doing that, I see:
`
AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was forbidden.
Severity level: Information
6/20/2024, 4:22:45 PM
TRACE
Authorization failed. These requirements were not met: ScopeAuthorizationRequirement:Scope= and scp or http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope is one of the following values: (API.Access) Handler assertion should evaluate to true.
Severity level: Information
6/20/2024, 4:22:45 PM
`

Also, if I loosen up the audience validation, and use <client or application id>/API.Access, I get the same error of  These requirements were not met: ScopeAuthorizationRequirement:Scope= and scp or http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/scope is one of the following values: (API.Access) which seems odd.

I believe api://application I'd/. default should work for you as it includes all the roles including API.Access, you can see that by decoding the token. You need to check the API which you are trying to authenticate using this token. I guess in your API, scp is set correctly

Decoding the token, I see:
{
"aud": "api://",
"iss": "https://sts.windows.net//",
"iat": 1718979839,
"nbf": 1718979839,
"exp": 1719066539,
"aio": "blah",
"appid": "",
"appidacr": "2",
"idp": "https://sts.windows.net//",
"oid": "",
"rh": "blah",
"roles": [
"Admin"
],
"sub": "f",
"tid": "",
"uti": "blah",
"ver": "1.0"
}
So, it does not have the API.Access scope in there when using .default.

Have you added API.Access role in the registered app then granted permission?

That's what we've tried to do, yeah, but I think my lack of Azure/Entra knowledge has resulted in me missing some vital step in the process here. I've tried to look for some examples of how one should configure a scenario where you have a function app using a managed identity that needs to call an API backed by an app service that exposes a required scope. The scope part seems to be what's tripping us up here.

@Cloudwalker added steps in my answer, please check
